# Reading multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array in JavaScript.

How do i read the data in the array by index ?

Example : If I want to read only country. Also if I want to read value of option in the frequency section below.

The value for the above array is derived from php array.

The code is as follows:

```
$array = ["country" => "AE,BH","city" => "AE-03-144384",'gender' => 'F','birth_date' => '1','frequency' =>    
  'value' => '10' 
  'option' => '1']
];
```

now in JavaScript I just coded :

```
  var newArray = ".json_encode($array). ";
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: It is an `object`.. To iterate `object`, use [`for..in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: you(or post editor) have missed one square bracket within array. So, where does the nested array start (if multidimensional array mentioned) ?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score -1):

But you have not an array you have an object. To get object's value by key use [] or '.' i.e.

```
var the_country = newArray['country'];
```